# empty record after delete from dataset

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset

after deleting record from the form there is an empty record until clos the form and reopen it '
below is my code

```
Try

        Dim delrecord As String = "delete  from  unitinfo where unitCode = '" & txtUcode.Text & "' "
        Dim delcon As New SqlConnection(sqlcon)

        delcon.Open()
        Dim cmdsqldel As New SqlCommand(delrecord, delcon)
        cmdsqldel.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

            Exit Sub
        Else

        End If
        delcon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: A side note, your messagebox is a bit too late.

Comment: ...and just about every line of code has a problem with it.  Start with learning about SQL Parameters and remove the empty Try/Catch.

Comment: And while you're at it, research how to handle disposable objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try

        If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?",
 "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

            Exit Sub
        Else
        Dim delrecord As String = "delete  from  unitinfo 
                               where unitCode = '" & txtUcode.Text & "' "
        Dim delcon As New SqlConnection(sqlcon)
        delcon.Open()
        Dim cmdsqldel As New SqlCommand(delrecord, delcon)
        cmdsqldel.ExecuteNonQuery()
        delcon.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Record Successfuly Deleted")
        /* Here you should refresh your datagridview if you have or any thing else*/
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally 
    ' This line executes whether or not the exception occurs.'
    If delcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then delcon.Close()

    End Try
```